# How to join a table within a user defined function whose name is provided as parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, user-defined-functions

**Context**

I have three tables in my SQL Server database: 1) School, 2) College, 3) University.

Then I have another table: Tags.

Each of the three tables (*School, College, University*) can have *Tags* associated with them. For which purpose I have three association tables: *SchoolTags, CollegeTags, UniversityTags*.

**Problem**

I am trying to create a user-defined function that will take the name of association table as parameter (i.e. 'SchoolTags') and the Id of the entity (school/college/university) and will return a list of tags associated with that *entityId*.

The issue I am having is I have got to join *Tags* with a table whose name will come in as parameter. For that I am creating a dynamic query. And we can not run dynamic queries in SQL Server user-defined functions.

**Question**

Any idea how can that be acheived?

Note: I want separate association tables as I have created and do not want to convert them into a generic association table and I do not want to add `If-Else` based on table names in my function so that if a new association table is created, I do not need to update my function.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Are you using identity int as PK in each association table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you desire is impossible. You cannot pass a table name as a parameter to a UDF and use dynamic sql in the UDF to then create and execute a statement that is specific to the table passed as the argument. You already know that you have no choice but to use if-else statements in your UDF to achieve your goal - it is your pipe-dream of "never having to update (or verify) your code when the schema changes" (yes - I rephrased it to make your issue more obvious) that is a problem.

There are likely to be other ways of implementing some useful functionality - but I suggest that you are thinking too far ahead and trying to implement generic functions without a clear purpose. And that is a very difficult and trouble-prone path that requires sophisticated tsql skills.

And to re-iterate the prior responses, you have a schema problem. You purposely created three different entities - and now you want a common function to use with any of them. So before you spend much time on this particular aspect, you should take some time to think carefully about how you intend to use (i.e., write queries against) these tables. If you find yourself using unions frequently to combine these entities into a common resultset, then you have might have a mismatch between your actual business and your model (schema) of it.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever language you are using, you would probably use `if`:

```
begin
    if table = 'school' then
    begin
        . . .
    end;
    else if table = 'college' then
    . . .
end;
```

The exact syntax depends on the scripting language for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Consider normalizing your database in related, logical groupings for **one** *EducationInstitution* table and **one** *JoinEducTags* table. Those tables sound like they maintain the same structure but of different typology and hence should be saved in one table with different *Type* field for *School*, *College*, *University*, etc.

Then, add necessary constraints, primary/foreign keys for the one-to-many relationship between all three sets:

[image: Database Schema Map]

You never want to keep restructuring your schema (i.e., add tables) for each new type. With this approach, your user-defined function would just need to receive value parameters not identifiers like tables to be run in dynamic querying. Finally, this approach scales better with efficient storage. And as you will see normalization saves on complex querying.

Comment: I completely agree with you but unfortunately I would not want to change the schema at this stage.

Comment: Why not? Per your note, you plan on changing schema (add tables) with additional Institution tables and Tag tables? Do you have large codebase that changes. Really heed this now instead of headaches down the road. It's not even hard to union all tables and create table.